# regex_replace return wrong string

Tags: c++, mustache

I try to do a little Mustache renderer:

```
std::string Mustache::render(const std::string& tmplt,const std::map<std::string,std::string>& context)
{
   std::string result = tmplt;
   for(std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator it=context.begin(); it!=context.end(); ++it)
   {
      std::regex reg("({{"+it->first+"}})");
      result = std::regex_replace(result,reg,std::string(it->second));
   }

    return result;
}
```

And I test this code with:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> context;

context["test"] = "render-test";

std::cout <<  Mustache::render("It's a simple {{test}}");
```

But It returns

> It's a simple {{test}}

instead of

> It's a simple render-test

Do you see what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: well your regex has `"("` and `")"` brackets so that might be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
std::cout <<  Mustache::render("It's a simple {{test}}", context);
```

Instead of

```
std::cout <<  Mustache::render("It's a simple {{test}}");
```

Comment: Thanks! It was just a big mistake!